# How to create a refund on ShopifyAPI

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to create a refund using Shopify API with the details in the documentation [here:](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/refund?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07#create-2020-10)
and this is the payload I'm sending:

```
{ currency: 'GBP',
notify: false,
refund_line_items:
  [ { line_item_id: '<line-item-id>',
   quantity: 1,
   restock_type: 'no_restock' } ] }
```

But I get this error:

```
StatusCodeError: 422 - {"errors":{"refund_line_items.line_item":["can't be blank"]}}
```

But `refund_line_items.line_item` is not mentioned in the documentation. I have checked the and the line_item_id is correct (is the ID of the variation ID, not the product ID, but I have tried using SKU and product ID, same result)

Other response in SO infers that this is because the line_item_id is incorrect but that's not the case. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow you but are you using the line_item.id or the variant.id, they are different. Example `id: 4697971523636` vs `variant_id: 32097460584500`  you can check  a random order and see the JSON response using a similar url to see the proper line_item.id => `/admin/orders/YOUR_ORDER_ID.json`

Comment: @drip I'm trying to create a refund as described per documentation, but the error I get is non descriptive (it complaints about a field that doesn't exist in the docs). I'm using the `variation_id` of the product, however I tried using the `product_id` and `id` as well and got the same result. Have you managed to create a refund with just the items (rather than the transaction) on Shopify?

Comment: I don't think you understood me properly, you shouldn't use the `variation_id`, but the `line_item.id`. Your order can have multiply `variation_id` but with different properties, so you **MUST** use the `line_item.id`. So in fact you are using the wrong ID and that's why it's probably mad at you.

Comment: @drip when I create the order, I save the `product_id` and the `id`. Do I need to make a request to get the `line_tem.id` in order to send this for the refund. Is that what are you saying?

Comment: Yes. If you are creating the order then the response of the creation should include the `line_item.id` and there will be no need to make another request. Refer to the api https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order#create-2020-10 and the response.